# Server has 2 IP addresses. How can I route 2 servers with 2 different ports to the 2 IPs on the same port

Tags: unix, ip, port, iptables, minecraft

I want to route:

```
127.0.0.1:25565 <-> 40.39.210.1:25565
127.0.0.1:25564 <-> 40.39.210.40:25565
```

Note that the 2 internal IPs are the same, but the ports are different, and the 2 external IPs are different, but the ports are the same.

Is this possible? I was looking at iptables, but I have absolutely no idea how to use it.

Comment: Would it not be easier to get the two different servers to bind to the appropriate IP on the appropriate port, or is there something that is preventing this from happening?  If I look here: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server.properties I see that it is possible to set the `server-ip` property to make this happen.

Comment: Yeah, but that would require support 2 servers. I'd rather just have one. I will definitely look into the server-ip thing. I thought that was just for broadcasting to minecraft.net's server list.

Comment: @msandiford Sure enough, server-ip works perfectly! That will make my life so much easier.

Comment: its not ip routing. its port forwarding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to capture the comment as an answer...

Would it not be easier to get the two different servers to bind to the appropriate IP on the appropriate port, or is there something that is preventing this from happening?

If I look on the minecraft wiki [here](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Server.properties), I see that it is possible to set the server-ip property to make this happen.

Comment: Well, I seem to have forgotten about you answering this. However, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you very much, my servers have been running successfully every since.